# Errors when trying to get SelectedValue from radio button list ASP.NET web form/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, selectedvalue

I am trying to get the values from an ASP radio button lists and store them to variables. I'm trying to use SelectedValue.

This error is displaying with my C# code:
Error   4   'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I'm new to ASP, so chances are it's something easy.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace frmArtUpl
{
public partial class uploader : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void ProcessArticulate_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string existingArticulateAddress = "";
        string newOrExisting = "";
        string publishLocation = "";
        string publicOrSecured = "";

        existingArticulateAddress = Request.Form["existingArticulateAddress"];
        newOrExisting = newOrExisting.SelectedItem.Value;
        publishLocation = Request.Form["publishLocation"];
        publicOrSecured = publicOrSecured.SelectedValue;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

    }
}
```

}

And here's the ASP:

```
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">New or Existing Articulate?</asp:Label>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="newOrExisting" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="true" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Existing" Value="false" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row hiddenOnLoad">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label">Enter Existing Articulate Address:</asp:Label>
                <input type="text" id="existingArticulateAddress" name="existingArticulateAddress" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label">Public or Secured?</asp:Label>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="publicOrSecured" name="publicOrSecured" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Public" Value="Public" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Secured" Value="Secured" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row hiddenOnLoad">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label">Where to publish?</asp:Label>                    
                <asp:DropDownList ID="publishLocation" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Lending" Value="Lending" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Loanliner" Value="Loanliner" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="TruStage" Value="TruStage" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a string local variable with the name newOrExisting which is the same as the radio button list id?

Comment: Oh man.  You're right!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

publicOrSecured in your current code is a string. You need to target your control and not name your variables with the same name. Something like this:

```
string _publicOrSecured = ""; 
_publicOrSecured = publicOrSecured.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using *this* keyword:

```
publicOrSecured = this.publicOrSecured.SelectedValue;
```

You're having problem because you named your string and your RadioButtonList with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your string and RadioButtonList has the same name!

string publicOrSecured = "";

asp:RadioButtonList ID="publicOrSecured"

Rename one!